# How to add event keydown to element HTML in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I tried for element `.page2`:

```
 $('.page2').on('click', 'keydown', function(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
   }  
}
```

But It does not work for me.

So I did error, I use now:

```
 $(".page2").on('keydown', function (e) {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to attach event to an element that has not been rendered yet. To avoid that, use [jQuery's ready event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
  $('.page2').on('click, keydown', function(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
   }  
  }
});
```

Or, you can attach a live event instead:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.page2', function(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
   }  
});
```

Finally, if you want to attach multiple events, you separate them by comma:

```
$(document).on('click, keydown', '.page2', function(e) {
   switch(e.which) {
   }  
});
```

Comment: It work only when I click on element div, may be to set autofocus?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your actual HTML structure. Please consider posting it, as well as what element you want to register click events on.